# How to define abstract property based on generic type

Tags: typescript

What I'm trying to do is to define type of a property in abstract class and initialize it in child classes.

[link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQE5IIYQKIBsYFsYB2YAPACoB8cAvHKXDAB5iEAmAznABQCWBAZjCRwASgEoA2gF04AfhFwAXHAIwAboIDcoSLDgBhABbcsLJITKUadRswLs4AVwIBrAgHsA7gSmy4AdTQoWCRiZDRMHHwiC3IfJQBZVChiNjAkXgBzABp-QODyLRBQVAAjVLQAYzA4CqxUNg4ApOCyajhUAghKAG9QOH64AHpB5RgYFnaKipgGuDA3GqMTMwI4XjmjDlr6tgA6PoHS8tQqxeNTQiVDc5WLUAP%20jJgwa%20XCTlElJqDBH16QAaAuBmMAOJCrMLoXZ8JBuXCcMCbXYVJYXAi7VSoLAOGYfUQPOAAX1AxKKIG2s2%20wUhEFaNlYHCcrk83kklHpdkaeUEFjg-0Bw38BlQ1W4HERYvoKDcSBkMgJKJuhDaPnquWaPJp2DwhBIFFikkKpNAFK5GqQAHFYQ5khR6EwGeqfiE7fyBoK-MLReLNlLYbL5QCBoq3qsaCoPHBEslypkclTBOQPkb7iBeMwkHwTvAAAqCNhuVZu-oEVD4JSxggZFNkiqF1JwDLWqAARjaEadwStbhtxDzSALBCTokKgpDaLWHFQUaS7TsazAAHIODBIrqp2Z6NxEYJO79pDKZzG0nG90hyKAmz3W8jUStdk8wJxF8xUovRABCW9Kgipk316pUBQdA23DGBIwTJAaT7fNCykYdRxGccVknOd2mAiAcg6CYYBOAx6DXIhUMgmCB0LcgcmQ5U3D4eg8IInUiKA%20AsG4Zx4B3doSjcdR9hAIDwhbb9Q12XAkk4SMqEoDxhLRUQgA)

---

I have type that returns different type based on whether passed argument is an array:

```js
type ArrayElement<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : never;
type Children<T> = T extends unknown[] ? Wrapper<ArrayElement<T>>[] : Map<string, Wrapper>;
```

The wrapper class defines its children property as type `Children<T>`:

```js
abstract class Wrapper<T = any> {
    // need access to children in this class.
    abstract children: Children<T>

    getChildren(): Wrapper[] {
        return Array.from(this.children.values())
    }
}
```

I would expect to initialize `children` property in child classes with either `Array` or a `Map`, but even with correct generic passed to `Wrapper` it doesn't work.

```js
class WrapperArray<T extends unknown[]> extends Wrapper<T> {
    // Property 'children' in type 'WrapperArray<T>' is not assignable to the same 
    // property in base type 'Wrapper<T>'.
    // Type 'Wrapper<ArrayElement<T>>[]' is not assignable to type 'Children<T>'.(2416)
    children = [] as Wrapper<ArrayElement<T>>[];
}

class WrapperGroup<T> extends Wrapper<T> {
    // Property 'children' in type 'WrapperGroup<T>' is not assignable to the same 
    // property in base type 'Wrapper<T>'.
    // Type 'Map<string, Wrapper<any>>' is not assignable to type 'Children<T>'.(2416)
    children = new Map<string, Wrapper>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAogGwgWwgO2AHgBUA%20KAXikKggA9hcATAZygAoBLHAMwjigCUAlAG0AulAD8AqAC4oOCADdeAbgCwAKFCQoAYQAW7NAzi4ipClVr0czKAFccAaxwB7AO44xkqAHUkYJBw%20PBIqBjYeObE3nIAsohg%20EzAcJwA5gA0fgFBxOoamogARilIAMbAUOVoiEws-olBRORQiDggpADemlB9UAD0A-IQEAxt5eUQ9VDArtWGxqY4UJyzhiw1dUwAdL39JWWIlQtGJrhyBmfL5pr7fekQwFdLuKyCco2BvN49Gv0AqCmYD2OArULIHZcOCuTCsYAbHblRbnHA7RSIND2abvQT3KAAX00RMKGi2My%20QQhIBa1kYLEcLg8XlEpDptgauV45igfwByOuuFa3jqOSa3Op6CwuAIJBi4lFL1Rt1JAPoKXevPxasRAteaMwiVY5XIpHKeP%20-RJJM05M54rgAHEYfYklY6PTeQS2R6OWLvsESFrLX0hn59IgquwWAjo9QEK44BIJPi9ajWgp3FAEkkyhlspTeMRNYqUTcSAV8ergJq%20YC%20rHdmnljtHjWAOTV9sWgHWu4aTj0OBcY7QAAKvCYrhWdb6OEQ2DkeZw6QKNrJ05SUHSLrAAEYMxAs4Wnbv8BO4FOcMXBAUw82hXHENnEm1bKtgO2WBAIjKWIhTGodgEV4f0gm8RMX1zVJ8zAotNB3VxXT3JEy1wVsnlYTtpk-QQAEJUMFHB%201tTcqgAsIDwoTM4Lgalz0nacxBvO9hgfFYnxWCjkGydpxggY59GoX88FWe0AwYy9p2IbJ2KgVwuGoQThOlUSAOgNB2CcaAQLaYpXGUPYNG4kAUPYnZDTAVgszIUh3EI-VBCAA)

Alright, so solution was easier than I thought. All I had to do, is to cast child class children property to `Children` type with correct generic:

```js
abstract class Wrapper<T = any> {
    abstract children: Children<T>;

    getChildren(): Wrapper[] {
        return Array.from(this.children.values());
    }
}

class WrapperArray<T extends unknown[]> extends Wrapper<T> {
    children = [] as Wrapper<ArrayElement<T>>[] as Children<T>l;

    test() {
        // works
        this.children.map(c => c)
    }
}

// Not so sure if {} is enough, because it allows arrays tho
class WrapperGroup<T extends {}> extends Wrapper<T> {
    children = new Map<string, Wrapper>() as Children<T>;

    test() {
        // works
        this.children.get('test')
    }
}
```